# Building Traffic & SEO

Tags: discussion, traffic

I noticed something interesting today.  This is the most trafficked post on Android.SE and it's less than a month old:

[Android 2.2 update for samsung Galaxy 3 (I5801 and I5800) (closed)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/android-2-2-update-for-samsung-galaxy-3-i5801-and-i5800-closed)

Just off hand I'd say that it's because Samsung Galaxy Update Android 2.2 are popular search terms.  It's a little ironic that the post with the most views is closed but I think it serves as a reminder that when we can we can be more mindful of keywords and SEO when asking/editing questions.

Comment: Off course it's hard to predict what will be popular in the future. So personally I think the most important thing is to ask as many question you have on Android here and not elsewhere ;-)

Comment: It's hard but not impossible.  As Google Insight tells us in the last 2 weeks the term "Android 2.3" has risen in popularity 300%.  In the interest of getting way ahead of the curve I am predicting that "Android 10.0" is going to be wildly popular... in a couple years ;o)

Answer (score 6):

Here was an interesting little experiment:

[Is there a Word Lens alternative/port for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3799/word-lens-alternative-port-for-android)

I knew that "Word Lens" was a hot topic yesterday, and that question it turned out to be the most viewed post yesterday.  In fact it's gotten 219 views in the last 20 hrs where as the next most recent post to get 200 views was asked on the 8th, taking a week and a half to get to 282 views.  Of the most popular search terms that brought people here over the last day "word lens android" got 90 and the next most popular was Samsung i5500 2.2 with 6 visits.

Now as far as questions, this wasn't the best one on the site, and it probably wasn't very useful to building membership because people probably came here found that there is no such app and left.

The value of the experiment is that it goes to show how being mindful of whats trending and making good titles with good keywords is helpful in getting people here.  Now ideally if we are to seed questions based on hot topics they'd actually be useful (Like Al's "When will my phone get Android 2.x?" questions) so when they get here they find some value and stay.

Comment: Yeah, Google likes our site, so if we're on top of new, we can get some decent page views

Comment: Huh, interesting experiment for sure.

Answer (score 3):

My [flickr account](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3920/why-is-android-claiming-i-have-multiple-flickr-accounts-and-not-allowing-me-to-u) question was on the site for less than 15 minutes before it became google #1 search result for "android multiple flickr account".

Previous searches had returned nothing useful.